# Why does imageio.imread sometimes return an `imageio.core.util.Array` instead of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imageio

In the [docs for imageio](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html#imageio.imread) it says that `imageio.imread` returns a numpy array. This has been my experience most of the time, but sometimes it returns an `imageio.core.util.Array` object. `imageio.core.util.array` is only mentioned once in the [imageio documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/imageio/downloads/pdf/stable/), and just noted that `imageio.core.Image` is an alias of it. I don't have a small example to provide because I only see it when I'm loading certain images, but I found that it happens in the [scipy image processing guide](http://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imageio.core.util.Array` is a *subclass* of the NumPy array, so it is correct to say that `imread` returns a NumPy array.  You can find the source code for `Array` at https://github.com/imageio/imageio/blob/efc560c514409e6425e2d7a839b4904b3d918fcf/imageio/core/util.py#L111.